# How do I add a fill color between lines on an svg?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, background-color

I have a svg image that contains multiples path and i want to add a background color inside my image.

I want my background color only between my black lines.

Do you know some tools please ?

For the moment, i think i will merge paths and create a polygon. But i think is not a good solution.

Svg:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 285 261" enable-background="new 0 0 285 261" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="none" opacity="1.000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
      stroke-width="2.000000"
      d="
M164.000000,33.500000
    C164.833328,43.333332 165.675537,53.165928 166.498123,63.000156
    C168.171005,82.999634 169.910492,102.993973 171.474167,123.002022
    C172.606567,137.491669 173.448700,152.003769 174.514191,166.498962
    C175.617111,181.503647 176.883545,196.496338 177.976624,211.501709
    C178.449387,217.991547 178.666656,224.500000 178.999985,231.000000
"/>
    <path fill="none" opacity="1.000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="2.000000"
          d="
M205.000000,33.500000
    C211.705887,48.559238 215.482666,64.496674 218.985229,80.503227
    C226.634079,115.458031 230.594208,150.944061 233.962753,186.503525
    C235.034225,197.814301 235.715897,209.163452 236.456482,220.502838
    C236.596710,222.649948 236.929367,224.891998 235.656830,227.817383
    C162.666672,234.509201 89.333336,235.739029 15.502701,228.046219
    C15.894063,223.319000 16.197031,219.659500 16.499998,216.000000
"/>
    <path fill="none" opacity="1.000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="3.000000"
          d="
M48.500000,33.000000
    C100.500534,33.000000 152.501068,33.000000 204.650604,33.000000
    C205.677261,27.124668 203.990173,21.838848 204.576874,16.250000
    C152.500000,16.250000 101.000000,16.250000 49.660480,16.250000
    C48.325832,18.359861 48.603340,20.451437 48.482582,22.498972
    C48.084709,29.245363 46.420258,35.630894 44.107647,42.038849
    C33.721039,70.818932 28.822332,100.874130 24.570915,131.010010
    C21.013802,156.224365 18.429388,181.560898 16.995337,206.999741
    C16.863691,209.335037 16.731928,211.673782 16.478987,213.997711
    C16.282843,215.799805 17.442259,215.521439 18.500000,215.500000
"/>
    <path fill="none" opacity="1.000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="3.000000"
          d="
M164.000000,17.000000
    C164.000000,22.166666 164.000000,27.333334 164.000000,32.500000
"/>
</svg>
```

It looks like :

[image: My object]

Comment: I dont see the svg code, but with css you can fill the paths: try: fill: black

Comment: Thanks @akicsike. I update my post. Its don't work because i want to put color inside object and not in border.

Answer (score 1):

You should use MASK: use the same path in the mask

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 285 261" enable-background="new 0 0 285 261" xml:space="preserve" style="">

<defs>
<mask id="mask-path1" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
<path fill="#fff" d="
M205.000000,33.500000
    C211.705887,48.559238 215.482666,64.496674 218.985229,80.503227
    C226.634079,115.458031 230.594208,150.944061 233.962753,186.503525
    C235.034225,197.814301 235.715897,209.163452 236.456482,220.502838
    C236.596710,222.649948 236.929367,224.891998 235.656830,227.817383
    C162.666672,234.509201 89.333336,235.739029 15.502701,228.046219
    C15.894063,223.319000 16.197031,219.659500 16.499998,216.000000
"></path>
</mask><mask id="mask-path2" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
<path fill="#fff" d="
M48.500000,33.000000
    C100.500534,33.000000 152.501068,33.000000 204.650604,33.000000
    C205.677261,27.124668 203.990173,21.838848 204.576874,16.250000
    C152.500000,16.250000 101.000000,16.250000 49.660480,16.250000
    C48.325832,18.359861 48.603340,20.451437 48.482582,22.498972
    C48.084709,29.245363 46.420258,35.630894 44.107647,42.038849
    C33.721039,70.818932 28.822332,100.874130 24.570915,131.010010
    C21.013802,156.224365 18.429388,181.560898 16.995337,206.999741
    C16.863691,209.335037 16.731928,211.673782 16.478987,213.997711
    C16.282843,215.799805 17.442259,215.521439 18.500000,215.500000
"></path>
</mask>
</defs>
    
<path fill="none" opacity="1.000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2.000000" d="
M164.000000,33.500000
    C164.833328,43.333332 165.675537,53.165928 166.498123,63.000156
    C168.171005,82.999634 169.910492,102.993973 171.474167,123.002022
    C172.606567,137.491669 173.448700,152.003769 174.514191,166.498962
    C175.617111,181.503647 176.883545,196.496338 177.976624,211.501709
    C178.449387,217.991547 178.666656,224.500000 178.999985,231.000000
" style="
    fill: aqua;
" mask="url(#mask-path1)"></path>
    <path fill="black" opacity="1.000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2.000000" d="
M205.000000,33.500000
    C211.705887,48.559238 215.482666,64.496674 218.985229,80.503227
    C226.634079,115.458031 230.594208,150.944061 233.962753,186.503525
    C235.034225,197.814301 235.715897,209.163452 236.456482,220.502838
    C236.596710,222.649948 236.929367,224.891998 235.656830,227.817383
    C162.666672,234.509201 89.333336,235.739029 15.502701,228.046219
    C15.894063,223.319000 16.197031,219.659500 16.499998,216.000000
" mask="url(#mask-path1)"></path>
    <path fill="black" opacity="1.000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3.000000" d="
M48.500000,33.000000
    C100.500534,33.000000 152.501068,33.000000 204.650604,33.000000
    C205.677261,27.124668 203.990173,21.838848 204.576874,16.250000
    C152.500000,16.250000 101.000000,16.250000 49.660480,16.250000
    C48.325832,18.359861 48.603340,20.451437 48.482582,22.498972
    C48.084709,29.245363 46.420258,35.630894 44.107647,42.038849
    C33.721039,70.818932 28.822332,100.874130 24.570915,131.010010
    C21.013802,156.224365 18.429388,181.560898 16.995337,206.999741
    C16.863691,209.335037 16.731928,211.673782 16.478987,213.997711
    C16.282843,215.799805 17.442259,215.521439 18.500000,215.500000
" mask="url(#mask-path2)"></path>
    <path fill="none" opacity="1.000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3.000000" d="
M164.000000,17.000000
    C164.000000,22.166666 164.000000,27.333334 164.000000,32.500000
" mask="url(#mask-path1)"></path>
</svg>
```

[image]